# Button not working

Tags: swift, uibutton, uialertview

I have this button who's calling a function(showActionSheetForPost) in another ViewController (TimelineViewController).

> My Button:

```
weak var timeline: TimelineViewController?

     @IBAction func moreButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        timeline?.showActionSheetForPost(post!)
    }
```

> The other ViewController (TimelineViewController):

```
class TimelineViewController: UIViewController, TimelineComponentTarget {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

// MARK: UIActionSheets

   func showActionSheetForPost(post: Post) {
        if (post.user == PFUser.currentUser()) {
            showDeleteActionSheetForPost(post)
        } else {
            showFlagActionSheetForPost(post)
        }
    }

    func showDeleteActionSheetForPost(post: Post) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Do you want to delete this post?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        let destroyAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .Destructive) { (action) in
            post.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if (success) {
                    self.timelineComponent.removeObject(post)
                } else {
                    // restore old state
                    self.timelineComponent.refresh(self)
                }
            })
        }
        alertController.addAction(destroyAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func showFlagActionSheetForPost(post: Post) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Do you want to flag this post?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        let destroyAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Flag", style: .Destructive) { (action) in
            post.flagPost(PFUser.currentUser()!)
        }

        alertController.addAction(destroyAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

> My problem:

when I touch the Button (moreButtonTapped) The Action Sheet doesn't appear.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You need to do like:

```
TimelineViewController().showActionSheetForPost(post!)
```

or set

```
weak var timeline: TimelineViewController()
```

Comment: When I change the weak var, I get this error:  Class 'PostTableViewCell' has no initializers.

Comment: And the first solution(TimelineViewController().showActionSheetForPost(post!)) didn't work

Comment: Did you set as `weak var timeline: TimelineViewController()`?

Comment: Yes I did, but I get this error `Stored property 'timeline' without initial value prevents synthesized initializers`

Comment: Now I got two more errors: `Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ;`  and `Expected declaration` , for the `weak var timeline: TimelineViewController()`

Answer (score 0):

@iamalizade

I took a screenshot of all the errors in my TimelineViewController

[The errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAFIW.png)